# PHP function that caches its response by re-writing itself after first call

Tags: php

for a long time I dreamed to be able to have a function that executes an algorithm only the first time it is called and saves the algorithm result.
Every other time the function is called it would just return the saved result.

I have found a way to do it, and it goes like this:

```
$myFunction = function() use ( &$myFunction ){

    // execute an algorithm and get a result
    $result = 10 * 5;

    // re-write $myFunction to return the result
    $myFunction = function() use ( $result ) { return $result; };
    
    // return the result (for the first function call)
    return $result;
    
};
```

It seems to work fine.
for example, if I execute this code:

```
$myFunction = function() use ( &$myFunction ){
    
    $result = (function() {
        echo 'this is calculated only once';
        return 10 * 5;
    })();
    
    $myFunction = function() use ( $result ) { 
        echo "\n" . 'this is a cached result';
        return $result; 
    };
    
    return $result;
    
};

echo "\n" . $myFunction();
echo "\n" . $myFunction();
echo "\n" . $myFunction();
```

I get the following:

```
this is calculated only once
50
this is a cached result
50
this is a cached result
50
```

My questions are:

1. Do you know of any problems using this method?
2. Do you know of another way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Seems more of a question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). From what I can see in the question, I'd say you simply created an incredibly convoluted way of storing a result in a variable.

Comment: It's a common practice to store the value and return it on the next call, this way might be slightly more efficient (need to check that) but seems much more complicated to debug in case of problems.

Comment: What's your imagined use case? In this example, with no input from outside the function, El_Vanja is right, this just obscures storing the result of some operation.

Comment: A problem with your code is that it does not work (correctly) for functions with arguments. To achieve look at Broshi's answer below.

Comment: Thanks @El_Vanja, I didn't knew code review

Comment: @OhadCohen I thought it would be problematic to debug too, but it worked flawlessly with xdebug.

Comment: @jjj yes, it is not supposed to have argument.

Comment: What you describe seems like a very simple case of caching to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fellow programmer gave me another, more elegant way to do the same thing, by using static variable inside the function.
It can even work with arguments and cache multiple results

```
function myFunction( $int ) {

    static $cache;

    if( !isset( $cache[ $int ] ) ) {
        $cache[ $int ] = $int * $int;
    }
        
    return $cache[ $int ];
        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example, as someone mentioned in the comments, is basically assigning a new function to the variable that was holding your original function. It is indeed a convoluted way to achieve your goal, and has several drawbacks which make it a not very suitable solution.

One immediate issue is expiring the cache, so that the real value can be calculated again. It isn't very straightforward with this approach. Another issue is that your cache implementation is tightly coupled to your code.

Consider readability, isolation and separation of concerns. Your function is doing at least 2 things: calculating a value and managing a cache, and it doesn't run in isolation: it creates side effects by reassigning an external (global?) variable. It's also not very readable: it isn't clear what parts are calculating the values and which are for managing the cache, and that's evident because you had to add comments to explain your code.

I would suggest a more Object Oriented Approach using a Design Pattern such as Chain of Responsibility or Decorator. You would have to define one class to calculate the value, let's say `ValueCalculator`. Then you would define another class called `ValueCalculatorFromCacheDecorator`, which would handle the cache and rely on `ValueCalculator` if the cache doesn't exist/has expired/is unavailable for some reason. In your code you would call it as:

```
$service = new ValueCalculatorFromCacheDecorator(new ValueCalculator());
$value = $service->execute();
```

Note that each class a single responsibility now. Your cache concerns have been isolated in `ValueCalculatorFromCacheDecorator`, whereas the main algorithm for calculating a value is in `ValueCalculator`. These two classes can also be easily unit tested now.

Some users mentioned using Redis/Memcached/etc. You don't really have to do that. You can use an in-memory data structure to implement a rudimentary cache if importing a whole Cache system like Redis is an overkill for your project. With the approach I suggested, you can even go further and create a specific Decorator for each Cache implementation, which would allow you to encapsulate the underlying cache system in a single class.

You can read more about these ideas here: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator and here https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility.

Answer (score -1):

You should be using a cache layer such as [redis](https://redis.io/) or [memcached](https://memcached.org/)

Here's an example how to implement this:

```
function myCoolAlgo($var1, $var2) {

   # Set the cache key which is built from these two vars
   $cacheKey = $var1 . $var2;

   # Check if we have this result in our cache
   # the myCache function is a helper that reads/sets data in the cache
   $result = myCache($cacheKey, 'get');

   // Note: if $result can be equal to 0, check it is not NULL
   if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
     # We have it in the cache, return it
     return $result;
   }

   # It's not in the cache, calculate it
  // Algorithem code comes here
  $result = 1234;

  # Store in the cache
  myCache($cacheKey, 'set', $result);

  return $result;
}
```